# javascript: time until page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

i am writing a animation with javascript and want to print to user loading time until all images loaded.

images set in html as: `<img src="" />`

**are there javascript code to know when all page loaded?**

i.e time until onLoad() event called

Comment: ahmed, @ThiefMaster is trying to say that when an answer solves your problem, it is considered polite to accept it (the big checkmark under the voting arrows). That lets the community know that you are actively engaged with your questions and aren't planning to dump and run, so to speak. It is of course not *required*. (Almost nothing on Stack Overflow is *required*.)

Comment: ok i did not know that there is a feature like this ... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this at the bottom of the page

```
<span id="imgsMsg"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgs = document.images;
var len = imgs.length;
var percent = 100;
var count=0;
var messagecontainer = document.getElementById("imgsMsg");
for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
   imgs[i].onload=function() {
     count++;
     messagecontainer = (percent - Math.floor((100/len)*count))+"% loaded"; // hope my math is correct ;)
   }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks it seem to be the answer, i will try it and give the result with you

Answer (score 2):

The best you can probably do is to track the number of images that have been loaded, and divide that into the total number of images remaining.  Something like this:

```
var total_loaded = 0;
$('img').load(function()
{
    total_loaded += 1;
    var load_progress = total_loaded / $('img').length;
    // you can now use load_progress to show the user a rough progress animation
} );
```

If you want a "time remaining" display, you'll need to fake it.  You could track the total time elapsed and compare that to the `load_progress` variable to get the remaining time, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hard to do, with  `$(window).load`:

```
var readytime = new Date().getTime();
$(window).load(function() {
    var loadingtime = (new Date().getTime() - readytime) / 1000; // in seconds

    $('#yourTimingField').text(loadingtime + ' seconds');
});
```

This measures the amount of time between the this part of the script and the loading of all subelements.

Comment: Hello i want to print for the user time until page load not time after page load.

Comment: example: 20% until all page load, 40% ..... 50% ..... 100% page loaded, you can start animation

Comment: @ahmed: That would be best done by adding images programatically using Javascript and afterwards manipulate DOM.