# Get Time for page to load in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Get Time for page to load in jQuery?

Comment: you can verify in firebug net panel , it shows the timelines for all the client calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the end of page load? `window.onload`?

```
var start = new Date();

$(window).load(function() {
   $('body').html(new Date() - start);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/tTc6a/).

If you're supporting newer browsers, you can swap the `new Date()` with `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 1):

With large pages or pages containing inline JavaScript, it is a good idea to monitor how long pages take to load.
 The code below is different from waiting until onload is fired and only measures page load time. [**[+]**](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/6-more-jquery-tips-text-searching-page-load-time-and-others.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = new Date();
</script>
… (your page) …
<script type="text/javascript">
new Image().src = '/load.gif?' + (new Date().getTime() - t.getTime());
</script>
</body>
<html>
```

load.gif can be a generic 1*1 pixel GIF. You can extract the data from your log files using grep and sed.

Also check here.

- [Page load time with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211414/page-load-time-with-jquery)
- [Javascript: time until page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794627/javascript-time-until-page-load)

---

One good diagnostic tool to help measure page load time is [**[jQTester]**](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/08/javascript-jquery-and-dom-load-time-tester/). It is a plugin that has you place small amounts of code at the top and bottom of your page. When the page finishes loading, you get a notification saying how long it took the page to load